# Removing a word from a list which appears one after the other

Tags: list, set, python-3.6

Lets say i have a list of words as shown below,

```
A=['ab','bc','cd','de','de','ef','bc']
```

I tried to use sets as seen below,

```
def remove_similar_words(self,sent):

    original_set = set()
    result = []
    for item in sent:
        if item not in original_set:
            original_set.add(item)
            result.append(item)
    return result
```

`sent` is list **A**.

The result of the above method would be

```
result=['ab','bc','cd','de','ef']
```

But, i need the result to be,

```
needed_result=['ab','bc','cd','de','ef','bc']
```

**Question** : How can i change my code to cater the requirement of producing the list `needed_result`?

Also i would like to avoid sets since i need to preserve the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def remove_similar_words(sent):

last = ""
result = []
for item in sent:
    if item != last:
        last=item
        result.append(item)
return result

A=['ab','bc','cd','de','de','ef','bc']
print (", ".join(remove_similar_words(A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you just need to check against the prior value in your iterator, not build a complete original_set.